# How to defer more than one js script

Tags: javascript

This works pretty well but I want to add more than just one .js file to it. Do How can I add more than one source to this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "yourdeferscripts.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably  you are looking for something like this?

### Alternative #1

The easiest way is using an Array:

```js
// Array of the .js file names
var script_list = ["yourdeferscripts.js", 'anotherdeferscripts.js']; 
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  // Runing through the array and appending to the body
  script_list.forEach(function(file) { // 
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    alert("This is " + file + " file.");
    element.src = file;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  })
}
if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

### Alternative #2

This loads a separate script using an onload function.

```js
function func1() {
  downloadJSAtOnload()
}

function func2() {
  downloadJSAtOnload2()
}

function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  alert("This is the first.");
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "yourdeferscripts.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function downloadJSAtOnload2() {
  alert("This is the second.");
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "yourdeferscripts.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(func1);
addLoadEvent(func2);
addLoadEvent(function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#EFDF95';
})
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: I like your first one. But how do I get it to stop popping up with a message for each file?

Comment: Also, this worked fine for 2 files, but when I tried to do it with more the page never actually loads?

Comment: in the first one just remove the alert(), if you adding more code be sure that is working.  Probably you need some library like JQuery~! If you think was useful please give me a point thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (not tested)

Create an array of the relevant file names,now loop through it and append it to the body

```
var _scripts = ["yourdeferscripts.js",'abc.js']; // array of js files name
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
// Use array forEach to loop through it and append to the body
_scripts.forEach(function(item){ // 
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = item;
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 })
 }
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```